# ubuntu gets slow when i play minecraft

Tags: server, minecraft

when I play minecraft it runs super well no lag at all, but when I use ubuntu with minecraft on it seems to be that ubuntu gets super slow it takes 5 seconds to get to my home folder it has never done that before I also try to run a bukkit server it works well but the I use a plugin and I get a timeout error ever since ubuntu got slow bukkit always crashed. can anyone help? i have 2.9 GB RAM. Thank You

Comment: Please read the section about optimizing the performance of Minecraft. There are many options that you can change to make the game play better as there are also options that if you change they can make your video card heat up faster or the CPU usage go to 100%. Play with them as mentioned in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

2.9 GiB seems too less to play Minecraft and using Unity the same time IMO. You should think about a RAM upgrade.

Alternatively install LXDE, a Desktop environment using less resources than Unity: `sudo apt-get install lxde-core`. On your Greeter ("Login screen") you can select the environment before login.